# unsure why res.send not sending my object to the front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

So I have tried everything and I can't figure out why the tumblr object is not passing through res.send to my frontend. Can anyone help?I tried res.json as well but that doesn't do anything. I got a promise error, an exception was caught but I'm unsure why. I assume it's related to the image object not passing through.

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {tag: "", images: ''};

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
   this.setState({tag: event.target.value});
  }

 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const sendTag = () => (
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.post('/tag', {
      tag: this.state.tag,
     })
      if(this.state.tag){
     resolve(console.log('in sendtag'))
    } else {
     reject (error)
    }
  }))
  .then(() => {
    axios.post('/images')
    .then(res => {
     console.log("AXIOS:", res)
      this.setState({images: res})
    })
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('IMAGES:', this.state);
  })
    .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
   });

  sendTag()

  }

 render (){
  return (
   <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           <input type="text" 
           onChange={this.handleChange} 
           className="searchTerm" 
      placeholder="Enter a tag" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </form>
    <div className="grid-container">

    </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Server.js

```js
//Express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//TUMBLR I
const tumblr = require('tumblr.js');

//TOKENS
const secret = require('./secret/config.js');

//MIDDLEWARE
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/public')));

//INITIATE API
const client = tumblr.createClient({
 consumer_key: secret.consumer_key,
 consumer_secret: secret.consumer_secret,
 token: secret.token,
 token_secret: secret.token_secret
});

// API
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    app.post('/tag', (req, res) =>{
     const tag = req.body.tag
     if(tag){
     resolve(tag)
    } else {
     reject (error)
    }
   })
}).then(function(tag){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     console.log('TAG', tag)
     console.log('tumble api')
      client.taggedPosts(tag, (error, data) => {
    if(data){
     console.log('data recieved')
     resolve(data)
    } else {
     reject (error)
     console.log('tumble api error')
    }
   })
    });
}).then(function(result){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     console.log('image to new variable')
     const images = result
     if (images){
      resolve (images)
     } else {
      reject (error)
     }
    })
}).then(function(images){
  console.log('send api')
   console.log('IMAGES', images)
   app.post('/images', (req, res) => {
    res.json(images)
   })
})

// FRONTEND ROUTE
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/index.html'));
});

//SERVER
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server running on localhost 5000!'));

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: are logs getting printed correctly? did you try verifying the rest api using rest client tools like postman?

Comment: process.on('unhandledRejection', function onError(err) {console.error(err);});   put this in your code, try running the app, it will show the errors...

Comment: so , I added the code and now the data shows up in the post object but that shouldnt be the case. thanks for giving me a starting point!

Comment: sorry didn't get you... you mean images are getting printed on the log or in rest response. ?

Comment: So now the images are showing up in the object on my frontend when i console log the results from my ajax. The data wasn't there before but now it shows up.

Comment: looks like i figured the issue... it is taking time to compute images... until than post api is not registered... better move app.post out side of promise chain... put a local varible on the file, just return it in the post call... you can replace this value once you promise chain completes... or set local varible to indicate error if promise chain has some error...

Comment: I tried that unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main problem is that your `res.json(images)` call is inside of an `app.post` declaration, so that would only get triggered if the client made a post request on `/images`.  If you remove the app.post and just call res.json in your last `.then` of the chain it may work.  However, I am not sure if your `/tag` route is getting set properly.  I don't see any reason for the promise chain or the separate `/tag` and `/image` route, because the only asyncrhonous call you make is to `client.taggedPosts`.  Therefore, I would recommend you define your `/tag` route and then put all the logic inside that route like so:

```
// API
app.post('/tag', function (req, res) {
    const tag = req.body.tag;
    if (!tag) {
        return res.send('please provide a tag');
    };
    console.log('TAG', tag)
    console.log('tumble api')
    client.taggedPosts(tag, function(error, data) {
        if(!data) {
            console.log('tumble api error');
            return res.send(error);
        }
        console.log('data recieved', data);
        console.log('image to new variable')
        const images = data;
        console.log('sending images');
        console.log('IMAGES', images);
        res.send(images);
    });
});
```

the `handleSubmit()` function on the client side can then be updated to make use of the `/tag` response as follows:

```
handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    function sendTag () {
        axios
            .post('/tag', { tag: this.state.tag })
            .then( function(images) {
                console.log("AXIOS response:", images)
                this.setState({images: images})
            })
            .then(function () {
                console.log('state:', this.state);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    sendTag();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, I am sending the tag to my server so I can use it with the tumblr's api and then send that data back to the client. So far, the tags and the tumblr api work but for some reason I can't send the data from the api back to the frontend

Comment: When you say you can't send the data from teh api back to the frontend, where in your logic is the app getting to before the information is not sent properly?  Are you getting to `console.log('IMAGES', images)` on the server side?  And if so, is it the `console.log("AXIOS:", res)` where you are not seeing the expected `res` data?

Comment: Yes, I can't get to console.log("AXIOS:", res). I get two errors: POST http://localhost:5000/posts 404 (Not Found) & Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404.

Comment: Ok, I still think the issue has to do with where the `/images` route is defined, and I still don't see any reason to define the `images` route as you have since the data you want is actually retrieved by the `/tag` route. If you really want to use the `/images` route, you would need to define it separately and pass information to it in the post call so it knows which images to get. Instead, I would update the front end to handle the data from the tag route, as that is where you are making the tumlr call. I have updated my answer to show how I suggest you simplify the client side component.